# Haproxy ACLs are firing incorrectly

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I have setup haproxy 1.8 on Ubuntu. I have to route traffic to different backends based on path. Following is the complere front-end of haproxy

```
frontend www_front
   bind *:80
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/example.com.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
   
#   mode http
#   option httplog

   http-request capture req.hdr(Host) len 64
   http-request track-sc0 src table per_ip_rates
   http-request deny deny_status 429 if { sc_http_req_rate(0) gt 3000 }  

   http-request capture req.hdr(User-Agent) len 64
   redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

   # redirect IP based browsing
   redirect prefix https://example.com code 301 if { capture.req.hdr(0) -i 210.56.21.204 }

   acl is_admin path_beg -i /ader10/admin
   redirect code 301 location /ader10 if is_admin

# ACLs

  acl hss_req path_beg -i /hss/
  use_backend ader10 if hss_req

  acl api_req path_beg -i /api/v1/
  use_backend hssApi if api_req

  acl req1 path_beg    -i /ima2
  use_backend devApp      if req1

  acl piwik_url path_beg   -i /piwik
  use_backend piwik      if piwik_url

  acl andr_req path_beg    -i /andr
  use_backend mobile     if andr_req

  acl iss_req path_beg    -i /iss
  use_backend issDirApp     if iss_req

  acl niss_req path_beg    -i /niss
  use_backend iss125     if niss_req

  acl ima_req path_beg    -i /ima
  use_backend imaApp     if ima_req

  acl irends_req path_beg    -i /irends
  use_backend irendsServer     if irends_req

  acl req_app1122 path_beg    -i /app1122
  use_backend irendsServer     if req_app1122

  acl ader10_req path_beg    -i /ader10
  use_backend ader10      if ader10_req

  acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
  use_backend letsencrypt-backend if letsencrypt-acl

  default_backend             apache
 
   log-format %ci:%cp_[%t]_%bi:%bp_%s_%{+Q}r_%ST_%Tq/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Tt_%B_%[capture.req.hdr(0)]


# LETSEncrypt Backend
backend letsencrypt-backend
    server letsencrypt 127.0.0.1:8888
```

Now when I test e.g., example.com/hss, some time it is routed to proper backend and some times default backend (apache). It is abnormal. WHere is the issue. Similarly, I have observed same behavior for /api/v1.
I have debugged a lot via logging and curl but not successful. Can someone help where is the issue.
Global settings are almost default.

Comment: You have 'mode http' commented out. If you don't have it set in the `defaults` sections then you are using 'mode tcp'. In the TCP mode, HAProxy doesn't fully parse HTTP requests and applies ACLs very early in the connection processing before the complete request has been received and this can cause different ACL matching depending on buffering, delays etc. Use 'mode http' explicitly when you are handling HTTP connections.

Comment: It is (mode http) set in default sir. Further, it is also set in each backend to http. Is that not enough

Comment: This issue looks weird, because it should work. Could you please post whole config? With globals/defaults and backends? Maybe there is something going on in backends. Also could you post some logs showing this behaviour? And `curl`, which caused them. One more thing. In `hss` and `api` ACLs you have trailing `/`, so if you request `/api/v1` instead of `/api/v1/` it won't match and go to default backend.